# How to get td value with same class and plaintext using simple html dom

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to find td values under BASIC EPS but there are two such columns and so it is making it difficult to select the 2nd column only (starting from value > 0.82 > 1.05 > .74 etc) which i want. I am doing this in a php script with simple html dom library so let me know how can it be achieved. The code i am using is as below. But this above code gives me basic eps values twice while i only need once in the 2nd column.

```
<tr height="22px">
    <td colspan="2" class="detb" width="40%">EPS Before Extra Ordinary</td>

    <td align="right" class="detb"></td>
    <td align="right" class="detb"></td>
    <td align="right" class="detb"></td>
    <td align="right" class="detb"></td>
</tr>


<tr height="22px">
    <td colspan="1" class="det" width="40%">Basic EPS</td>

    <td align="right" class="det">0.82</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1.05</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">0.74</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1.00</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">0.96</td>
</tr>


<tr height="22px">
    <td colspan="1" class="det" width="40%">Diluted EPS</td>

    <td align="right" class="det">0.82</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1.05</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">0.74</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1.00</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">0.96</td>
</tr>


<tr height="22px">
    <td colspan="2" class="detb" width="40%">EPS After Extra Ordinary</td>

    <td align="right" class="detb"></td>
    <td align="right" class="detb"></td>
    <td align="right" class="detb"></td>
    <td align="right" class="detb"></td>
</tr>


<tr height="22px">
    <td colspan="1" class="det" width="40%">Basic EPS</td>

    <td align="right" class="det">0.82</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1.05</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">0.74</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1.00</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">0.96</td>
</tr>


<tr height="22px">
    <td colspan="1" class="det" width="40%">Diluted EPS</td>

    <td align="right" class="det">0.82</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1.05</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">0.74</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">1.00</td>
    <td align="right" class="det">0.96</td>
</tr>
```

---

```
$mn=$html->find("td.det"); 
if($mn->plaintext=='Basic EPS'){ 
    foreach($mn[1] as $r1){ 
        if($r1->plaintext == 'Basic EPS'){ 
            $next_td = $r1->next_sibling(); 
            $qeps10 = $next_td->plaintext; 
            echo $qeps10."<br>"; 
            $next_td_1=$next_td->next_sibling(); 
            $qeps9 = $next_td_1->plaintext; 
            echo $qeps9."<br>"; 
            $next_td_2=$next_td_1->next_sibling(); 
            $qeps8 = $next_td_2->plaintext; 
            echo $qeps8."<br>"; 
            $next_td_3=$next_td_2->next_sibling(); 
            $qeps7 = $next_td_3->plaintext; 
            echo $qeps7."<br>"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so - you have shown us the html but not the code to process the html

Comment: You should probably add that to your question :)

Comment: no need for any complication, if you want the first found element, just directly put the index in the second argument, `->find('td.det', 0)`, now you'll get the first, then continue with getting the next siblings

Comment: but there are more tds with class  'det' above the html code i gave. So I can't use  find('td.det', 0). I want reference of td with it's plaintext.